# Web Page Loaded Event using FiddlerCore

Tags: fiddlercore

When I open a URL in the browser (Internet Explorer), using FiddlerCore I can get all the raw HTTP requests/responses. However 
I would like to identify the time when a Web Page is completely loaded in the browser. Is it possible to do this? Is there any event which I can attach to?

Thanks

Shashank

Answer (score 0):

You could start a Stopwatch when you connect to the webpage,this would be in the `FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest`. And stop the stopwatch when the `Session.state` in the `FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete`. But that would only be for the first request. If you want to accurately measure a complete "page load" you should do this for all resources (.js/.css/etc.) on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I want to detect when the page is completely loaded in the browser. The number of raw requests is not the same every time, as noticed through Fiddler. so want a better way to measure this

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this out of the box in FiddlerCore.